# Atom IDE autosave option?

Tags: atom-editor, autosave

I'm using Atom IDE as I'm trying to learn coding.I really like everything about it.However, I really would like to know if I have the option for enabling autosave? What I mean is when you write even a single line of code, it should apply it immediately instead of I save the file.Pushing (Ctrl+S) whole day is really annoying.I know that PyCharm has this option, does Atom have?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an add-on package named autosave. It should help you. I'd google "Atom.io autosave" and go to the site https://atom.io/packages/autosave. You can download it from there.  There are also other helpful sites from google search. The autosave is initially set to off. I don't know how to turn it on but there are directions on the site.